# What is needed in order to query through mongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am running mongoDB on Ubuntu. I have a database called 'temporary'. Inside that database I have a collection called 'questions'.

Using mongo on the command line I was able to successfully insert objects into the 'questions collection'. So far so good. My next step was to write a program in JavaScript that would run and insert some more objects into the collection. That worked fine, I was able to connect to my collection and add more to it.

Now here's where I'm having problems. In a JavaScript program, I would like to make queries and retrieve certain data from my 'questions' collection. My code looks like this:

```
var mc = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
//connect to database
db = mc.connect('mongodb://localhost/temporary', function(err,db){
    var myCollection = db.collection('questions');
    var newArray = myCollection.find().toArray();
    db.close();
}
```

I believe I am connecting to my collection correctly because that's how I connected to it to add entries. My problem is with the find() method and the toArray() method.

From my understanding find() let's me search through my collection and ends up returning something called a cursor. I want to take the objects and put them into an array using toArray().

The problem is this line gave me an error:

```
var newArray = myCollection.find().toArray();
```

The error says "Error: Callback is mandatory". So I ended up searching and found this website: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html

From there I decided to try:

```
 var newArray = myCollection.find().toArray(function(err, items){
     if(err){ console.log("An error occured");}});
```

With this, I keep getting "An error occured", printing out. Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? It's obviously with the toArray() method but I don't know what the cause for the error is. I feel like my code is pretty much just the bare bones right now and I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

To clarify, I get no error when I just do the find() method by itself but for some reason adding .toArray() breaks my code. I thought perhaps it's because my  my find() call has parameters  but I get the same error even when searching for objects that I know are in the collection, so it's not that.

I'm connecting to my database. I create a collection 'questions' that already should exist and have objects that were inserted into it. I use find() to do a query, try retrieve objects into an array, and then I want to close the database.

Comment: What does `err` contain in the `toArray` callback?

Comment: Could you also show us the actual error `console.log(err)` instead of your custom message?

Comment: When I print the actual error using console.log(err) I get:

"MongoError: Connection Closed by Application"

Comment: That would be from your `db.close()` call that you're calling before the async callback occurs.  Try moving that call to the end of your callback (or just remove it all together for now).

Comment: Ah I figured it all out, thank you very much! It all just clicked. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

change

i hope this might help you..

```
   MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/temporary", function(err, db) {
        var myCollection = db.collection('questions');
         myCollection.find().toArray(function(err,resu)
                            {
                                    console.log(resu);
                 }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That did fix the problem actually. I was wrongly under the impression that by calling .toArray() it would return an error that I could use in as a variable. But I guess it turns out 'resu' (in your example) actually has the Array with the object files.

As someone new to JavaScript. How does the logic  work behind this though. toArray() is a method call. It has a function as a parameter; 'function(err, resu)'. That function has two output parameters, err and resu? Resu being the output parameter for the array being created?

Really do appreciate the help thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try restructure and test your code as follows:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,    
    assert = require('assert');

var db = new Db('temporary', new Server('localhost', 27017));
// Establish connection to db
db.open(function(err, db) {    
    var myCollection = db.collection('questions');
    // Retrieve all the documents in the collection
    myCollection.find().toArray(function(err, documents) {
          if(err){ console.log("An error has occurred"); }
          assert.equal(1, documents.length);
          db.close();
    });
});
```